# Ruby on rails - Stripe : "you did not set a valid publishable key"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, api-key

I have a problem I am following step by step this tutorial to include the gem stripe to my rails application : https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails

But I have an issue when I launch my payment:

> you did not set a valid publishable key. Call `Stripe.setPublishableKey()` with your publishable key.

The tutorial I am following doesn't use this method `Stripe.setPublishableKey()` and it seems working as well ...

I am using a `.env` file to get the API keys and I use the test keys from the tutorial.

Any idea for the solution ?!

Thank you very much :) If you need more information please tell me

My actual code is a copy/paste from the tutorial I use.

### Edit 1

I don't understand why but it working when I push the project on Heroku ... but I still don't understand why it's failing on local

Answer (score 1):

From the guide you linked:

> The application makes use of your publishable and secret API keys
>   to interact with Stripe. An initializer is a good place to set these
>   values, which will be provided when the application is started.
>
> Add the following to config/initializers/stripe.rb:
>
> ```
> Rails.configuration.stripe = {
>   :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
>   :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
> }
>
> Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
> ```
>
> These keys values are pulled out of environmental variables so as not
>   to hardcode them. It’s best practice not to write API keys into your
>   code, where they could easily wind up in source control repositories
>   and other non-private destinations.

Have you added that data into config/initializers/stripe.rb ?

If so, you may need to restart your server as the files in config/initializers are only loaded on server startup

Comment: Yes I putted this code in my config/initializers/stripe.rb file ... and also I tried to restart the server with rails s but unfortunatelly the issue is still here

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a .env file to get the API keys and I use the test keys from the tutorial.

Rails don't autoload environment variables from `.env` file. So, in the tutorial author set required variables from the console before server start, but you use `.env` file.
To fix that use gem [dotenv-rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv): just add in your Gemfile(not need add the same lines as in gem description)

Comment: I am using the gem dotenv-rails, but it's not working ... my .env files was in a .gitignore file so I putted my .env files in my root to try also but there is no change, I find the same issue

Comment: @Malus_khanot, I checked this tutorial, all work perfectly with .env file. You must check your credentials - maybe you wrote the different names of keys or copy not full keys

Comment: @Malus_khanot, can you provide that .env file?

Comment: Maybe it's an issue on my .env file ... here my .env file content with the test keys from the tutorial :                                                                  > PUBLISHABLE_KEY = pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh                                                                           
SECRET_KEY = sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome the same type of error in another tutorial by changing the last line of the stripe.rb file to:

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:secret_key]
```

with the key being saved in the credentials.yml.enc file in rails 5.2